# How to define username and password in row of picker

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a picker 5 row `(0, 1, 2, ...5)` and I want to define if I select `row:0` and I click button

"Login" will show alertView to add Username and Password which Username and Password in row:0

must be A and A only when I click "Login" in alertView go to(modal) View:A but Username and

Password not A and A show alertView "Username or Password wrong"

and row:1 working same from row:0 but Username and Password must be B and B only and

go to(modal) View:B not View:A

Any suggestions?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    _Data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Place1", @"Place2", @"Place3", @"Place4", @"Place5", @"Place6", nil]; 
}


- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
{ 
return 1; 
} 

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    return [_Data count]; 
} 

-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    return [_Data objectAtIndex:row]; 
} 

- (IBAction)ShowID:(id)sender 
{ 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login" message:@"Enter    Username and Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil]; 
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput]; 
    [alert show]; 
}
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    _Data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Place1", @"Place2", @"Place3", @"Place4", @"Place5", @"Place6", nil];
}

Comment: -(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_Data count];
}

-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_Data objectAtIndex:row];
}

Comment: - (IBAction)ShowID:(id)sender
{
    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login" message:@"Enter Username and Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
    
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
   [alert show];

}

Comment: move code in question please. You can edit your post.

Comment: we will help you with pleasure

Comment: I can't move code in question because it Error.

Comment: try insert code in new line, select ones and then press Ctrl+K

Comment: I moved. It is all right?

Comment: Yes. Hope your code will help us with your problem :)

Comment: Try create two array. Second with login data. For index in first array you then take your login from second array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary* dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Place1", @"place", @"TSViewController1", @"vcclass", @"User1", @"userName", @"qwerty", @"password", nil];
    NSDictionary* dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Place1", @"place", @"TSViewController1", @"vcclass", @"User2", @"userName", @"wwwrtt", @"password", nil];
    _Data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: dict1, dict2, nil];

}

-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[_Data objectAtIndex: row] objectForKey: @"place"];
}

- (IBAction)ShowID:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger indexPicker = [_pickerView selectedRowInComponent: 0];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Login"
                                                    message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Enter Username and Password for %@", [_Data objectAtIndex: indexPicker]]
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles: @"Login", nil];

    [alert setAlertViewStyle: UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Login"])
    {
        NSInteger indexPicker = [_pickerView selectedRowInComponent: 0];

        NSString* username = [[_Data objectAtIndex: indexPicker] objectForKey: @"userName"];
        NSString* password = [[_Data objectAtIndex: indexPicker] objectForKey: @"password"];
        NSString* yourUsername = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        NSString* yourpassword = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text;

        if ([username isEqualToString: yourUsername] && [yourpassword isEqualToString: password])
        {
            NSString* viewControllerClassName = [[_Data objectAtIndex: indexPicker] objectForKey: @"vcclass"];
            Class classOfViewController = NSClassFromString(viewControllerClassName);
        UIViewController* viewController = [[classOfViewController alloc] init];
            [self presentModalViewController: viewController
                                animated: YES];

            // or [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

In .h:

```
@interface ...
{
    NSArray* _DataLogin;
    NSArray* _Data;
    UIPickerView* _pickerView;
}
```

Then you should create your custom view controllers. You can also use presentModalViewController instead of the pushViewController.

Comment: how to coding go to View2, View3?

Comment: Can you explain me about view1 behavior? may be you want go to view1 if user choice row1 and view2 for row2?

Comment: Name of row is Name of place which different place. And View1 is Data of Place1 and View2 is Data of Place2 and View3 is Data of Place3. Which different style.

Comment: I had to have segue way(modal)?

Comment: IT not go to next view.

Comment: can you place breakpoint on line [self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated: YES]; and check viewController on nil?

Comment: It alert "Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and dose not have an identifier for runtime access via - instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier".

Comment: Yes of course. I updated my answer (it is 3 lines after NSString *viewControllerClassName = ... line).

Comment: Will I doing something with View2?

Comment: I can't use code "presentModalViewController: viewController animated: YES".

Comment: You may read my answer.

Comment: if I use "[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];" It not go to View2. Why?